# Error Launching Android Studio 2.1

Tags: java, android

My operating system: windows 10
System type:64 bit
i have already installed JDK (1.8.0_66) and have set the environmental variable (JAVA_HOME with value C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_66) even then when ever i try to open android studio i get an error like this:

> No JVM installation found.Please install a 64-bit JDK.
>   If you already have a JDK installed,define a JAVA_HOME variable in Computer>System Properties>System Settings>Environmental Variables.

PS: I have tried with some solutions like defining JDK_HOME variable, but nothing resolved.

Comment: Sounds like you installed the x86 version not the x64 jdk

Comment: you should choose : full 64bits or full x86, but you can't work across, so easiest to do is uninstall the jdk, download a 64bit version, and install that.

Comment: install JDK 64bit version

Answer (score 0):

> install jdk1.7.0 and reset it to android studio

Comment: this should be a comment

Comment: @HuyN I can't comment -->  **Reputation < 50**